# Drawing point to another point in R?

Tags: python, c, dataframe, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

I have a information of migration data of different countries to Mexico. I want to represent it in a sanky. I am new to R and having a difficult time to produce it. Can someone please help me to achieve this? The destination is Mexico, so all the data flow will be to one point

```
df

Country         2013       2014       2015      2016       Dest
UK              1200       1200       1207      1400       Mexico
China           630        700        800       940        Mexico
Canada          1000       1000       950       920        Mexico
Brazil          820        670        550       230        Mexico
France          400        200        700       700        Mexico
Australia       440        350        340       780        Mexico
```

Sankey diagram example:
[image]

Comment: It's better to ask a question in one *specific* language: either `r` or `python`. In R, there exist quite a few packages that allow you to draw Sankey diagrams (`ggsankey`, `plotly`, `networkD3`). What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Please include these code attempts in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different way to visualise your data. We use `plotly` to create a dynamic animation of the flow of migrants into Mexico over time.

```r
# Need to reshape data from wide to long and prepare data for plotly
data_long <- data %>%
    rename(source = Country, target = Dest) %>%
    pivot_longer(matches("\\d{4}"), names_to = "year") %>%
    pivot_longer(c(source, target), values_to = "country") %>%
    mutate(node_id = as.factor(country))

# Plotly Sankey diagrams need a link list that gives 0-based indices 
# (instead of node names)
link_list <- data_long %>% 
    select(-country) %>%
    mutate(node_id = as.integer(node_id) - 1) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "node_id") %>%
    arrange(year) %>%
    as.list()
    
# Now we're ready to plot
library(plotly)
plot_ly(
    type = "sankey",
    orientation = "h",
    node = list(
        label = levels(data_long$node_id),
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20),
    link = link_list,
    frame = ~link_list$year) %>%
    animation_slider(currentvalue = list(prefix = "Year: "))
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```r
data <- read.table(text = "Country         2013       2014       2015      2016       Dest
UK              1200       1200       1207      1400       Mexico
China           630        700        800       940        Mexico
Canada          1000       1000       950       920        Mexico
Brazil          820        670        550       230        Mexico
France          400        200        700       700        Mexico
Australia       440        350        340       780        Mexico", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A different option could be using [ggalluvial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html) to create an alluvial workflow of the values per country over the years and the total per year. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
# remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
library(ggalluvial)  
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -`Country`:`2016`) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", value))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, alluvium = Country)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Country, colour = Country),
                alpha = .75, decreasing = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Migration to Mexico") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. How can I add the country names in the y -axis? I want both the values and the country name